# Where are the server/bot logs with xcode6-beta4

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode6, xcode-bots

I wish to look at the logs generated by Bots. My bot seem to be in Running.. state all the while and I want to look at the output that is generated generated.

[image]

I can't kill the bot from UI, like in a previous version to look at the bots.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the location is /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/

But to see the contents under each directory you would have to change sharing and permissions of each of them and peek into them.